# How to configure spacing before closing XML tag on Android Studio?

Tags: xml, android-studio

When applying "Reformat command" (<kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>⌥</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>) on a XML file Android Studio adds a space before closing tags.

For example, the following code

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/panic"/>
```

After "Reformat code"  will become

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/panic" />
```

Is it possible to avoid that? Where can I configure the space before closing XML tags?

---

I'm using Android Studio 2.1.2 on MacOSX El Capitan 10.11.5.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the options.

`Settings->Editor->XML->"Other" Tab`.  In the `Spaces` group uncheck `in empty tag`.